# What is a recommended height for tile edging?

Tags: tile, backsplash

I'm trying to put up a tiled mosaic back splash and I'm trying to figure out the profile height for the edging. My tiles are 1/4" (6mm) thick.

Should I be getting an edge where the profile height matches my tiles or should I get one slightly thicker to account for the thinset?

[image: tile edging example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With larger tile that may span irregularities, I would advise 1/16 higher to end up flush.

With mosaics, I would go for the same height.  Too much thinset with mosaics makes a grout line mess, oozing up and needing extra cleaning.

If you are using unbacked glass mosaics, be sure to skim coat the whole field with a white thinset before pulling.a notched trowel for the final setting bed. Then flatten the ridges for a smooth, void free bed that won't show variations through the glass

Answer (score -1):

You can use the same height square tile trim or straight trim to protect and enhance ceramic tiling.  You can check [Aluminum square edge trim](http://www.honstaralu.com/72-aluminum-square-edge-trim.html) for more information. In my experience, at both ends, you have to use internal or external end cap to cover them.

Comment: Welcome! Please see the [faq#promotion] for the rules on self-promotion on this site.